# Why do gamma-rays and neutrons produce different decay times in scintillation pulses from the same compound?

Tags: photons, radiation, neutrons, particle-detectors, gamma-rays

The basis of pulse shape discrimination is that gamma-rays and neutrons have different decay times of their electronic pulses. What makes gamma-rays and neutrons interact with the same compound interact differently such as to produce different modes of decay? For example, in zinc sulfide, heavy charged alpha particles have 3 decay times of 70 ns, 700 ns and 10 us. but electron decay time is only about 10 ns. Why?

Comment: Well, they are different particles that transfer energy to the material in different ways.

Comment: @JonCuster yes, that is the basis of pulse shape discrimination. but what are the different ways exactly? is it difference in energy state transitions? i meant to ask, HOW are they different?

Comment: Maybe if you give a link were the different decay times are measured one could quess at an answer. In general alphas have twice the charge of an electron and  electrons are very much lighter than alphas, and these differences should affect the ionsateion path  for the same energy, let alone for different energies as expected from alpha and neutron decays.

Answer (score 0):

> [Neutron interactions in organic scintillators produce scattered protons through elastic scattering;
> protons have a short range and generate a high concentration of triplet states, which decay by
> delayed fluorescence. By contrast, gamma ray interactions in organic scintillators produce
> scattered electrons. Electrons have a longer range than protons and generate a lower
> concentration of triplet states (electrons are more likely to produce excited singlet states, which
> decay by prompt fluorescence) (Zaitseva 2011a). The difference in the pulse shape of the signal
> as a result of the ratio of prompt to delayed fluorescence produced by different types of radiation
> makes PSD a popular method of high-energy neutron detection in an environment where gamma
> rays are present.](https://www.pnnl.gov/main/publications/external/technical_reports/PNNL-21609.pdf)